# arm template PowerShell custom script

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

As part of my ARM Template, I need to execute PowerShell script to install Failover cluster windows feature. However, the script run for at least 10 min then fails with following error.

> new-azResourceGroupDeployment : 11:18:03 - Resource
>   Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions
>   'DI-ukwest-DB1/extensions' failed with message '{   "status":
>   "Failed",   "error": {
>       "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
>       "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
>       "details": [
>         {
>           "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
>           "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'extensions'. Error message: \"Failed to download all
>   specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The remote server returned an
>   error: (400) Bad Request.\"."
>         }
>       ]   } }'

My script is

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1),'/extensions')]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
      "location": "[variables('varlocation')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyindex(1))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": [
            "https://XXXXXarmtemplets.file.core.windows.net/powershellscripts/sqlcluster/InstallWindowsFeaturs.ps1"
          ]
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InstallWindowsFeaturs.ps1",
          "storageAccountName": "XXXXXarmtemplets",
          "storageAccountKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "WinFeatures",
        "count":"[variables('varvmCount')]"
      }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: No, That is why I added protectedSettings

Comment: oh, ok i'm being silly. also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#examples-of-downloaded-files) suggests you need to do `-File \"./powershellscripts/sqlcluster/InstallWindowsFeaturs.ps1\"` instead of what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

That error is pretty reliable - the ps1 file can't be downloaded by the extension.  I noticed you have "file" .core.windows.net instead of "blob" which is the common use case - so one thing to check...

Also, you can log onto the VM and check the logs, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#troubleshoot-and-support